# Trouble with custom driver

Tags: python, drivers

I need to write a custom driver function (because the algorithm I need is too complex to put into a single line). So, I thought I'd try making a custom driver...

I opened the file editor, pasted my function:

```
import bpy

def spinnerSlowdown(frame, cutoff, slowdownframes, offset):
  r = radians(frame * -18) + offset 
  if frame < cutoff:
    return r
  elif frame < cutoff + slowdownframes:
    factor =  ((frame - cutoff) / slowdownframes)
    factor = 1 - (factor - 1)  * (factor - 1)
    newFrame = cutoff + (slowdownframes * factor)
    ret = radians(newFrame * -18) + offset
    return ret
  else:
    newFrame = cutoff + slowdownframes
    return radians(newFrame * -18) + offset
    
    
bpy.app.driver_namespace['spinnerSlowdown'] = spinnerSlowdown
```

... saved it, then ran the script (both with the arrow and Text / Run Script). No errors. (If I type some garbage into the script and run, I get an error, so I know it's at least compiling).

But, when I try to call that fn from a driver: `spinnerSlowdown(#frame, 200, 100, radians(130))`

It gives me the "Error: Invalid Python expression" message.

If I try to call it from the Python console:

```
>>> spinnerSlowdown(1,2,3,4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'spinnerSlowdown' is not defined
```

So, it looks like my fn isn't visible.

Any ideas?

I'm a complete noob to writing Python inside Blender... so be kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your driver expression `spinnerSlowdown(#frame, 200, 100, radians(130))` has two little problems:

- First, remove the `#` before frame. The `#` is used to create a driver automatically, but you already are in a driver, so to say.
- `radians` is unknown in your function. Add this line right after `import bpy` in your script: `from math import radians`.

And if you want to call your function from the console, you need to do

`>>> bpy.app.driver_namespace['spinnerSlowdown'](...)`

Comment: `radians` is not unknown in drivers, all functions from `math` module are available (also added to the whitelist in the safe python). Indeed the script needs to import radians.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady yes, you're right, i misread the error message first (it was unknown in the custom function, not in the expression). I fixed my answer, thx again.

Comment: The 'import radians' thing was the trick (the # was just an experiment). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`spinnerSlowdown(#frame, 200, 100, radians(130))` is indeed not a valid Python expression. Specifically the `#` character is unexpected.

The `#frame` means two things:

- `#` - create a driver with the following expression
- `frame` - current frame number

So either type `#spinnerSlowdown(frame, 200, 100, radians(130))` in a normal field to create a new driver with that expression, or skip the `#` and type `spinnerSlowdown(frame, 200, 100, radians(130))` in an already driven field (highlighted in pink) or in the driver editor.